# Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.3 Navbar Aligning Navbar Header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm having difficulty to centering my navbar brand logo.

currently, my logo will align far to the left.

what I want actually to align it center from the first link. Kindly find below for the sample :
[image]

Please find below my code at JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QSa8v/3/

```
<div id="navbar">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-custom">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ren-nav-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">
                    Toggle navigation
                </span>
                <span class="icon-bar" />
                <span class="icon-bar" />
                <span class="icon-bar" />
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CMEnIo7.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ren-nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 6</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Really need your kind answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at here : http://jsfiddle.net/QSa8v/4/

**HTML changes :**

```
<div id="navbar">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-custom">
        <div class="navbar-header col-xs-3 myheader">    // CHANGE HERE
            <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ren-nav-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">
                    Toggle navigation
                </span>
                <span class="icon-bar" />
                <span class="icon-bar" />
                <span class="icon-bar" />
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mybrand">     // CHANGE HERE
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CMEnIo7.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ren-nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav mybar">          // CHANGE HERE
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 4</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 5</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">LINK 6</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS added :**

```
.mybar {
    margin-left:0px !important;
}
.mybrand{
     float:none !important;   
}

.myheader{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: its work! thanks. but need to figure out something when viewing using mobile phone. thanks again!